# Allow trusted SSL Certificate in iPhone

Tags: iphone, https, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate

I know how to implement "https" using `NSURLConnection` for async requests. It can be achieved using a couple of delegate methods. Now my problem is , I have my entire app working using sync request and it is impossible to change it into async at this point. Could anyone please tell me how to implement SSL Verification for synchronous request in  `NSURLConnection`?

Answer (score 1):

I have never found a way to. NSURLConnection sync request are extremely limited in functionality. I wrote a wrapper around NSURLConnection I call GPHTTPRequest. Should allow you do to sync request with the ability to allow self-signed and works a lot like ASIHTTPRequest, but is based on NSURLConnection instead of being the lower level CFNetwork framework.  link is here:

https://github.com/daltoniam/GPHTTPRequest

also quick code example:

```
GPHTTPRequest* request = [GPHTTPRequest requestWithString:@"https://selfsignedURLYouwanttoaccess"];
request.allowSelfSigned = YES;
[request startSync];
NSLog(@"response: %@",[request responseString]);
```

also for the sake of options you can check out:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking

but I would recommend GPHTTPRequest just because I wrote it and know how it works. ;) Any questions let me know.

Comment: thanks @daltoniam :) btw did u wrote this ? and what do you mean by wrapper ? could you please explain more on that ? thanks once again :)

Comment: Correct, I wrote that GPHTTPRequest library. By wrapper I mean, it is using NSURLConnection in the class. So it is built off NSURLConnection framework and my class "wraps" the APIs to make it simpler and more robust. My goal was to create a replacement for ASIHTTPRequest as it was no longer being updated. If you found my answer useful please accept it(checkmark thing next to my answer).